# How can I join two tables in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have got two tables in my project. I want to get Note with username of the note writer. How can I join this table in LINQ?

Note Entity :

```
 public class Note : MyEntitesBase
    {      
        public string Tittle { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool IsDraft { get; set; }
        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        public virtual EvernoteUser Owner { get; set; } 
        public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; } 
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; } 

        public virtual List<Liked> Likes { get; set; }

        public Note()
        {
            Comments = new List<Comment>();
            Likes = new List<Liked>();
        }
    }
```

EvernoteUser Entity:

```
 public class EvernoteUser : MyEntitesBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
             /*Exc */
        public Guid ActivateGuid { get; set; } 


        public virtual List<Note> Notes { get; set; } 
        public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; } 
        public virtual List<Liked> Likes { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: looks like you are asking for:  note.Owner.Username - where note is a Note entity

Comment: Sometimes (not always) I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when I access the username parameter with note.Owner.Username.

Comment: Then there was no Owner set during creation - you need to protect against this.  i.e. Owner is not mandatory as a constraint at creation

Comment: Show your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *eager load* the Owner table data when you make the query against Notes so that when you access the .Owner property it is not null. For example:

```
Note noteWithOwner = _context.Notes
    .Include(x => x.Owner) // Eager load the Owner table data into the object graph.
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == noteID);
```

Comment: I'm sending it like this view. There is no error when creating View for the first time, but an error is received after a certain time. I think the entity framework is dispose of dbContext.

Comment: Do you have different queries to access the data?Do they all have the .Include(...) method in the chain? Have you checked the database data directly via SQL to check that the Owner.Username is not null?

Comment: I checked via database, there is no note without owner.